# Creating an implementing class that reuses objects of other implementations of the same interface

Tags: java

I want to create a class that does not implement any method of an interface, but extends any implementation of A with it's own methods.

Let's assume we have the following:

```
public interface A {
    public void a();
}
```

and

```
public class B implements A {
    @override
    public void a() {
        System.out.println("a");
    }
}
```

I now want to create a class `C` that also `implements A` and takes another random implementation of `A`:

```
 public class C implements A {
        public C(A a) {
            //what do I need to do with a here?
        }
        public void c() {
            System.out.println("c");
        }
    }
```

Now if I have the following:

```
A b = new B();
A c = new C(b);
c.a();
```

The output should be "a".

I can't just

```
public class C extends B {
...
```

as C is supposed to be able to work with any implementation of A, not just B.

I also can't

```
  public class C implements A {
        private a;
        public C(A a) {
            this.a = a;
        }
        @override
        public void a() {
            a.a();
        }
        public void c() {
            System.out.println("c");
        }
    }
```

since that would mean that I have to redirect every single interface method and rewrite C whenever something changes with A.

Is there any way to handle that problem in Java?

For another example, replace A: List; B: ArrayList; C: FooList; a(): size()

Comment: "since that would mean that I have to redirect every single interface method and rewrite C whenever something changes with A" - well if A changes, you *have* to change every implementation of A. That's just the way it is.

Comment: Is it possible for you to make A abstract class instead of interface?

Comment: @Manish no, see my example of List. Let's just think I want a method .count() that returns .size() + 1. The problem is that ArrayList for example would not work if C expects AbstractFooList as input argument.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yes, I would also accept an alternative to implements. I know this comparison might sound stupid, but in JS, it would be no problem to just use any method of the input implementation of A, regardless of what it is, as long as that input is a propper implementation of a.

Comment: @user1206791: You shouldn't try to treat JS and Java the same way. They're completely different languages, with different idioms. A design which is appropriate in JS may be inappropriate in Java and vice versa.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yes of course, that wasn't my intention at all. I just mentioned that to show how easy this problem could be addressed in JS.
Just for the record, I consider JS to be a total PITA and the amount of time I spent fixing issues resulting from the lack of type safety is tremendous. And no, our JS engine doesn't even support strict mode.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a dynamic proxy, which automatically implements all the methods of an interface by delegating to a concrete implementation of this interface. That's not trivial, but not so complex to do either, using Java's [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) class.

A concrete example of such a proxy, which "adds" methods to any instance of PreparedStatement by wrapping it, can be found at https://github.com/Ninja-Squad/ninja-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ninja_squad/core/jdbc/PreparedStatements.java

Comment: Thanks, I think that might be a feasible approach, though it's quite a bit more complicated than I hoped.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no way to do it in Java, other than your last code snippet. Various IDEs will help you with the code generation, though, and marking all methods `@override` will mean that you'll get a warning or an error if your implementation of `C` doesn't exactly match `A`'s interface.

For Eclipse (and, apparently, IntelliJ), see the "Generate Delegate Methods" command.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was affraid of. My last proposal would be extremely complicated as there would be so many parts where any change in the interface would require rewriting code.
Think of precompiled libraries that contain C. So any change in A would also require changing C.

Comment: As a rule, interfaces should change *very seldom*, so hopefully you won't have to do it that often. But when you do, you can just `select all`, `delete`, and re `generate delegate methods`.

Comment: I don't think the actual handling in the IDE would be much of a problem, it's more of a responsiblity breach that I'm worried about.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not going to immediately help you, but if you used Java 8, you could solve this with *defender methods*, which are methods implemented in the interface.

You would then, for each existing implementation class, add your own class which `extends` the class and `implements` your additional interface with the defender methods. The methods would be "mixed into" your class.

Java 8 is just around the corner, though, so it is not a far-off solution. Oracle has promised it will release it by the end of this quarter, meaning in less than a month and a half at the latest.

Comment: Let me just answer like this: "Java 7? What's that?"
But thanks for the remark, sounds cool and I'll look at that out of personal interest.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to handle that problem in Java?

Basically, no.

What you are describing a wrapper class that delegates calls to the wrapped method.  The only way you can implement that (in regular Java) is to implement all of the methods and have them make the calls.

---

Another alternative would be to use the Proxy class ... which will effectively *generate* a dynamic proxy.  The problem is that this requires an InvocationHandler that will (I guess) use reflection to make the call to the wrapped object.  It is complicated and won't be efficient.

If your goal is simply to avoid writing code, I think this is a bad idea.  If your goal is to writing the same code over and over (e.g. because you have lots of exampled of `C` for a given `A`), then consider coding an abstract class for the `C` classes that deals with the wrappering / delegation.

---

It would also be possible to generate the wrapper class `C` from nothing, using the BCEL library or similar.  But that's an even worse idea (IMO).

Comment: I wouldn't dismiss dynamic proxies so fast. After all, they're the basis of Spring's AOP for example, used in thousands of real applications.

Comment: And a source of lot of classloader leak pain ... from what I've heard.  And it is one thing to use a framework that does this, and completely another to do it yourself, by hand.